# The uniqueness of homogeneous matrices of some geometric transformations

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, projective-geometry, homogeneous-spaces, geometric-transformation

Given the description of a specific geometric transformation, the homogeneous square matrix of it can be obtained per the methods described by many textbooks.

For example,  many text books suggest the homogeneous matrix of a reflection be constructed by multiplying a series translations, rotations and so on to the reflection about some axis plane, which can be obtained immediately easily.

Specifically, the homogeneous matrix reflection about plane $x+2y+z+5=0$ can be obtained as:

$$-\dfrac{1}{3}\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
 -2 & 2 & 1 & 5 \\
 2 & 1 & 2 & 10 \\
 1 & 2 & -2 & 5 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -3 \\
\end{array}
\right]$$

and more generally, a reflection about the plane $a X+b Y+c Z+d=0$ can be written into :

$$\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
 -a^2+b^2+c^2 & -2 a b & -2 a c & -2 a d \\
 -2 a b & a^2-b^2+c^2 & -2 b c & -2 b d \\
 -2 a c & -2 b c & a^2+b^2-c^2 & -2 c d \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & a^2+b^2+c^2 \\
\end{array}
\right]$$

though the construction process for a specific transformation generally is not unique (not only with the non-unique origin reflection about axial reflection, but non-unique in matrix factors' selection and consequences), and of course it is not the definition of the transformation, it   actually proves the *existence* of the specific *reflection*'s homogeneous matrix. But how can we prove the *uniqueness*?

I have similar puzzles, i.e., the proof of the uniqueness of their homogeneous matrices,  on such geometric transformations as translation, central projection, rotation, shear, reflection, and so on.

Comment: You can’t, at least not without adding a caveat: they are unique _up to an irrelevant scalar multiple_. Just as the homogeneous coordinates of a point are really an equivalence classes, so are homogeneous matrices that represent projective transformations.

Comment: the uniqueness means unique up to a non-zero scalar

Comment: As Berci says in his answer, all of these matrices represent _linear_ transformations of $\mathbb R^4$. Leverage that and examine what two matrices that represent the same transformation do to the standard basis vectors.

Comment: I mean I believe it is true; but I doubt whether there exists any academically serious and precise proof up to now. As a matter of fact, I also doubt how to prove the uniqueness of the original reflection or other transformation used when constructing the general ones; addtionally, I included central projection, which is generally singular and not a linear transformation which must be nonsingular. In order to prove the uniqueness, first there should have to be clear and precise definition, I also doubt such existence so far.

Comment: I use "Given the *description* of $\cdots$" not  "Given the *definition* of $\cdots$" because of my above concerns.

Comment: You can tag the question as 'reference-request'. Unfortunately I can only offer the references what e.g. wikipedia says.

Comment: thank you Berci! wikipedia is already the best I can see, but including some of the textbooks I tried to search for about 20 years (yes!), none of them give clear and precise definitions needed.

Comment: You’ve misunderstood my comment: all of these _projective_ transformations of $\mathbb{RP}^3$, including central projection, are, when represented via homogeneous coordinate vectors and matrices, _linear_ transformations of $\mathbb R^4$. You wouldn’t be able to represent applying the transformation as a matrix multiplication otherwise. Lift from the projective space to $\mathbb R^4$ and then it should be a straightforward matter to use that linearity to prove uniqueness up to scalar multiple.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the origin is fixed, these are all ordinary *linear transformations*, so they are uniquely determined by their matrix, as any linear map $\varphi:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m$ is just a (left) multiplication by the matrix $M=[\varphi(e_1)\,|\dots|\,\varphi(e_n)]$ where $e_1,\dots,e_n$ is the standard basis of $\Bbb R^n$.
So that, $M\cdot v=\varphi(v)$ for every $v\in\Bbb R^n$.
[Observe that, for any matrix, $M\cdot e_i$ gives the $i$th column of $M$.]

Conversely, if $M\cdot v=\varphi(v)$ for all $v$, then in particular, it applies to the standard basis vectors $e_i$, which shows that the $i$th column of $M$ *must be* $\varphi(e_i)$, thus proving uniqueness.

If the origin is not fixed, we talk about *affine transformations* and bring in one more coordinate and the projective plane/space.
Specifically, we embed $\Bbb R^n$ into $\Bbb R^{n+1}$ at the affine hyperplane $H:=\{(x_1,\dots,x_n,1):x_i\in\Bbb R\}$, and apply the transformation $H\to H$ by extending it to a *linear transformation* $\Bbb R^{n+1}\to\Bbb R^{n+1}$. 
This extension is only unique up to a scalar multiple.

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Affine_transformations.

Comment: when talking about *uniqueness* which I do believe is true, I expect precise proof or links to such proofs published, better with peer reviews if published in serious academic publications, or can be peer-reviewed and verified without too much hard creative work.

Comment: I mean I believe it is true; but I doubt whether there exists any academically serious and precise proof up to now. As a matter of fact, I also doubt how to prove the uniqueness of the original reflection or other transformation used when constructing the general ones; addtionally, I included central projection, which is generally singular and not a linear transformation which must be nonsingular. In order to prove the uniqueness, first there should have to be clear and precise definition, I also doubt such existence so far.

Comment: Hmm.. I might have misread (misinterpreted) the original question. I thought that the word '*homogeneous*' refers to keeping the origin fixed in your transformations. Allowing translations actually changes things a bit, and then it's the *projective geometry* which helps in the interpretations, and then the homogeneous matrices are only unique up to scalar multiple.

Comment: Right. That is what I mean. I use "Given the description of ⋯" not "Given the definition of ⋯" because of my above concerns about the existence of precise definitions from the viewpoint of projective geometry.

Comment: Ok. Do you understand the case when the origin is fixed? Linear transformations. Like rotation around the origin, reflections, projections, shearing, etc.

Comment: Yes. Some of the affine transformations cannot be represented into square matrices.

Comment: I extended my answer. Please specify your further uncertainties. By the way, I think, any book on elementary affine/projective geometry should contain what you're looking for.

Comment: There are unarticulated assumptions used in your proof or answer. e.g., Is there definition that defines geometric transformation as linear transformation(this is the premise)? for a specific nonsingular reflection, and a specific central projection, how to use the standard bases to determine the transformation itself? I wonder why in the wikipedia link there are no such info

Comment: The assumption all transformations are linear transformation is not always true unless we use homogeneous coordinates. e.g., translation and central projection. To prove the uniqueness of homogeneous linear transformation, the fundamental theorem in projective geometry might be more reasonable to me

Comment: I am finally able to upvote your answer. thank you!